# Javascript onClick Before After Image effect with slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want do a before/after image effect slider like, when click on a image it will replace with another image. And again when click on replace image it will back to previous image.

Onclick function can change image only at once. 
This is my working demo [Codepen](https://codepen.io/RashedulAlam/pen/vwrvrE)

```
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ccsnkJS/image-11.jpg" 
    onclick="this.src ='https://i.ibb.co/R7d7Lw6/image-13.jpg';">
```

Before that I've tried with mouseover and mouseout function. Demo [Codepen](https://codepen.io/RashedulAlam/pen/joKQbj)

```
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/wNsz0MW/image-11.jpg" onmouseover="this.src ='https://i.ibb.co/R7d7Lw6/image-13.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/ccsnkJS/image-11.jpg';">
```

But unfortunately mouseover and mouseout function does not work on mobile device. Using mouseover and mouseout , when tap on screen new image replace but when I tap on screen again image not back to previous image.

It would be a best solution if I can achieve it with mouseOver and mouseOut in all device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all your code defined within the html element itself, things are a little tricky.

Basically you can use the html **data-*** attribute to store arbitrary data - like the url for the second image.

```
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/ccsnkJS/image-11.jpg" data-secondImg="https://i.ibb.co/R7d7Lw6/image-13.jpg">
```

Inside the **onclick** handler we need to check which url is currently set for the img element's **src** property and compare it to data-secondImg. If it's different use the url from secondImg and store the current url in a backup variable. If it's not different use the url from the backup variable.

Here's an example:

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/ccsnkJS/image-11.jpg" onclick="if(this.src!=this.getAttribute('data-secondImg')){this.old=this.src;this.src=this.getAttribute('data-secondImg')}else{this.src=this.old;}" data-secondImg="https://i.ibb.co/R7d7Lw6/image-13.jpg">
```

### Followup

If you want to use multiple events - onMouseOver and onClick - which should trigger the same action and in case you have a lot of images, it's better to define the action as a function once and just reference it by it's name.

This example reacts to both onMouseOver and onClick events:

```js
function swap(t) {
  if (t.src != t.getAttribute('data-secondImg')) {
    t.old = t.src;
    t.src = t.getAttribute('data-secondImg')
  } else {
    t.src = t.old;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/88/64/64" onClick="swap(this)" onMouseOver="swap(this)" data-secondImg="https://picsum.photos/id/76/64/64">
```

Comment: Thank you. It's an amazing solution. Curios mind wants to know is it possible to store text data and back with click like this process.

Comment: Glad I could help! The concept can be applied to other html elements too of course. Here's an example for a div `<div data-text="my replacement text" onclick="if(this.firstChild.data!=this.getAttribute('data-text')){this.old=this.firstChild.data;this.firstChild.data=this.getAttribute('data-text')}else{this.firstChild.data=this.old;}">the initial text</div>`

Comment: Sorry for disturb again. One more last query. Is it possible to use onclick and onmouseover together!!!

Comment: No problem - I've expanded my answer above to cover onMouseOver.

Comment: Thank you a lot again. But in mobile device at first tap image not changes. From second tap it's working fine. All image of the slider doing same behavior. updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/RashedulAlam/pen/rgrWYg)

Comment: I'm afraid this happens because on a mobile device the click and mouseOver event fire at the same time. So it replaces the initial image with the second and again with the first in one go. On subsequent calls it works as intended because the mouseOver event will not fire again as long as you didn't click somewhere outside the image. You can probaby overcome this issue by embedding some logic that checks how much time has passed since the last call to swap(). If it's too fast (maybe below 20ms or so) don't change the image.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this could be to create two seperate images.

Make one of the images perform the desired action on hover, and the other perform the desired action on click.

Finally, use CSS (or JS) to hide the element that is not required for a given screen size or device type.

```
<style>
  .mobile {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .desktop {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .mobile {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .desktop {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
</style>

<img
  class="mobile"
  src="https://i.ibb.co/ccsnkJS/image-11.jpg"
  onclick="this.src ='https://i.ibb.co/R7d7Lw6/image-13.jpg';"
/>
<img
  class="desktop"
  src="https://i.ibb.co/ccsnkJS/image-11.jpg"
  onmouseover="this.src ='https://i.ibb.co/R7d7Lw6/image-13.jpg';"
  onmouseout="this.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/ccsnkJS/image-11.jpg';"
/>
```

Comment: Good idea. But with this solution in mobile device it not possible to back previous image. I think i've to merge previous solution given by @obsecure.